# JAVA Class for getting FileType outside of checking the path

Tags: java, file-type

Im hoping to find a way to identify the file type through some java library instead of extracting the file name/path and getting the extension.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a question on if someone uploads a pdf file but actually changes the extension to .doc and tries to upload it. Thus i would need to know how to catch this exception.

Comment: A PDF starts with 25 50 44 46 (hex signature), you can read the first bytes to guess the file types. This is typically what I did when I implemented the image file format detection within JOGL: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/texture/ImageType.Util.html#getFileSuffix(byte[])

Comment: Thanks @gouessej i guess i can read the bytes to help determine the file type